# How can I extend the disabled time of touchpad after keypress so it won't activate?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, touchpad

When I type, my hands tend to slide along the trackpad a little, moving the cursor around and often throwing my typing off. Despite the fact I have the setting enabled to disable touchpad when typing, this still occurs. The problem is because the delay isn't long enough - it only ignores mouse events that happen simultaneously with keypresses. How can I edit the code so that there is a slight delay in time before the touchpad is reactivated? I am running Linux Mint 17.2, with Cinnamon as my DE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how this task is managed in cinnamon, but if you are using *Synaptics touchpad* then you should install [xf86-input-synaptics](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-synaptics/) driver and then run `syndaemon` program. It is very likely that the driver is already set on your system, so just try

```
syndaemon -d -i 3
```

Option means `-d` means to run program as a daemon, and `-i` sets idle time in seconds after key press. As always `man syndaemon` gives you full documentation about more options.

Comment: So I would assume then that the option in my settings uses `syndaemon`. Is there any way of me editing some sort of configuration file or shell script so that the setting will, by default, do so?

Comment: @Rohan I don't uise neither linux-mint, nor cinnamon so don't know its configuration. Concerning modifier keys - yes it is possible, just add `-k` option.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Your answer worked like a charm.